# Apple video adapters: Mini-DVI to DVI + DVI to video?

Tags: macbook, dvi, adapter, s-video, mini-dvi

I have:

- a Macbook (which has Mini-DVI output)

  - an Apple Mini-DVI to DVI adapter (so I can hook up my Macbook to my DVI LCD)
- a Mac mini (which has DVI output)

I see that I can get a DVI-to-Video (s-video and composite) adapter from Apple that will let me hook up my Mac mini to my TV set (which has only component, s-video, and composite -- nothing digital).  So far so good.

Question: Will that same adapter also let me hook my Macbook to my TV?  That is, can I hook Macbook -> Mini-DVI to DVI -> DVI to video -> TV set, and see picture?

I know there are digital/analog/integrated variants of DVI, and it's not at all clear to me what pins these things have and what signals they're sending.  One website I found suggested that it would work, and another suggested that it wouldn't even physically connect.  So I'm looking for, ideally, someone who's actually tried it, or has these adapters sitting around to try.

I know I can buy 2 adapters (Mini-DVI to Video, and DVI to Video) to do this, but at $20 a pop I'll avoid that if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The most recent negative review on the product page](http://store.apple.com/us/product/M9267G/A), which unfortunately there isn't a permanent link to, answers this question, and if you look closely at the plug picture you can see that it has the four pins around the long tab that are the analog-video lines. The DVI adapter does not have the corresponding pin sockets, as it is a digital-only (DVI-D) output.